# Can't install/update nuget packages

Tags: windows, visual-studio, nuget-package, vcpkg

I run into an issue when trying to compile an open-source github project ;

I launch Visual Studio Community, then try to update the nuget packages but to no avail ; I get the error

> "An error occured while trying to restore packages: Unable to find
> version '1.0.0' of package 'vcpkg.C.dev.vcpkg'."

I tried looking on the internet, installed vcpkg and did everything right, but still, it stays here. I tried to check if I can do anything by restoring nuget packages, but still, nothing is working

Comment: Vcpkg is not from nuget. Is this a C++ project?

Comment: It's a c# project
I know it's not a NuGet package, but I installed it from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: Have you read their documentation? Please be more specific in what you tried, since I cannot see how C# is involved here.

Comment: I have no clue either, but when I tried to compile the C# project, I had this error about vcpkg
I've git clone vcpkg, launched the bootstrat.bat, added the environment vars,

Comment: That's weird. Can you show the project file of that C# project? It's strange they depend on vcpkg (and it would be even more strange if you had to build that yourself)